# Error when setting up Ansible AWX

Tags: docker, ansible, docker-for-windows, docker-compose

Im setting up Ansible AWX on my Windows 10 machine using docker-compose. When running the install playbook `ansible-playbook -i inventory install.yml` I get the error below. Im able to see the login screen but unable to login using the default credentials. Ive tried updating my docker-compose version but no luck. Any ideas how to solve this error?

Im following the steps from this github repo https://github.com/ansible/awx/blob/17.0.1/INSTALL.md

Docker-Compose version = 1.29.2
Docker version = 24.0.7
Ansible version = core 2.15.6
Python version = 3.10.12

TASK [local_docker : Run migrations in task container]

> ************************************************************************************************************************************************fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "docker-compose run
> --rm --service-ports task awx-manage migrate --no-input", "delta": "0:00:00.373472", "end": "2023-12-19 10:55:04.590566", "msg":
> "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2023-12-19
> 10:55:04.217094", "stderr": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n
> File "/home/jvieyra/.local/bin/docker-compose", line 8, in
> \n    sys.exit(main())`n  File
> "/home/jvieyra/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/compose/cli/main.py",
> line 81, in main\n    command_func()\n  File
> "/home/jvieyra/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/compose/cli/main.py",
> line 200, in perform_command\n    project = project_from_options('.',
> options)\n  File
> "/home/jvieyra/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/compose/cli/command.py",
> line 60, in project_from_options\n    return get_project(\n  File
> "/home/jvieyra/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/compose/cli/command.py",
> line 152, in get_project\n    client = get_client(\n  File
> "/home/jvieyra/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/compose/cli/docker_client.py",
> line 41, in get_client\n    client = docker_client(\n  File
> "/home/jvieyra/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/compose/cli/docker_client.py",
> line 124, in docker_client\n    kwargs =
> kwargs_from_env(environment=environment,
> ssl_version=tls_version)\nTypeError: kwargs_from_env() got an
> unexpected keyword argument 'ssl_version'", "stderr_lines":
> ["Traceback (most recent call last):", "  File
> "/home/jvieyra/.local/bin/docker-compose", line 8, in ", "
> sys.exit(main())", "  File
> "/home/jvieyra/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/compose/cli/main.py",
> line 81, in main", "    command_func()", "  File
> "/home/jvieyra/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/compose/cli/main.py",
> line 200, in perform_command", "    project =
> project_from_options('.', options)", "  File
> "/home/jvieyra/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/compose/cli/command.py",
> line 60, in project_from_options", "    return get_project(", "  File
> "/home/jvieyra/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/compose/cli/command.py",
> line 152, in get_project", "    client = get_client(", "  File
> "/home/jvieyra/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/compose/cli/docker_client.py",
> line 41, in get_client", "    client = docker_client(", "  File
> "/home/jvieyra/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/compose/cli/docker_client.py",
> line 124, in docker_client", "    kwargs =
> kwargs_from_env(environment=environment, ssl_version=tls_version)",
> "TypeError: kwargs_from_env() got an unexpected keyword argument
> 'ssl_version'"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}`

Inventory file

```
localhost ansible_connection=local 
ansible_python_interpreter="/usr/bin/python3"

[all:vars]
dockerhub_base=ansible

awx_task_hostname=awx
awx_web_hostname=awxweb
# Local directory that is mounted in the awx_postgres docker container to place the db in
postgres_data_dir="~/.awx/pgdocker"
host_port=80
host_port_ssl=443

docker_compose_dir="~/.awx/awxcompose"

pg_username=awx
pg_password=awxpass
pg_database=awx
pg_port=5432

admin_user=admin
admin_password=password

# Whether or not to create preload data for demonstration purposes
create_preload_data=True

secret_key=awxsecret

# Proxy
http_proxy=http://proxy:3128
https_proxy=http://proxy:3128
#no_proxy=mycorp.org

# AWX custom virtual environment folder. Only usable for local install.
custom_venv_dir=/opt/my-envs/

ca_trust_dir=/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug in the latest Docker version (7.0) causing this. The workaround is using a slightly older version of Docker in the Python pip environment when installing Ansible AWX:

```
pip uninstall docker
pip install docker==6.1.3
```

GH posts on the issue:

- https://github.com/geerlingguy/internet-pi/issues/567
- https://github.com/docker/docker-py/issues/3194